# reuse function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've this easy code that works fine.

*html snippet:*

```
<div class="iconbar" ng-controller="icons">
    <span ng-click="iconclk()">icon</span>
    <div ng-if="icon1">value</div>
</div>
```

*and the js:*

```
app.controller('icons', function($scope)
{
    $scope.icon1 = false;
    $scope.iconclk = function(){
                         if(!$scope.icon1) $scope.icon1 = true;
                         else $scope.icon1 = false;
                     };
});
```

now the problem is that i wont to pass `icon1` as a parameter in `iconclk` to use the same function with multiple icons (icon1,icon2,icon3...)
I've tried this:

*html:*

```
<div class="iconbar" ng-controller="icons">
    <span ng-click="iconclk(icon1)">icon</span>
    <div ng-if="icon1">value</div>
</div>
```

*and the js:*

```
app.controller('icons', function($scope)
{
    $scope.icon1 = false;
    $scope.iconclk = function(icon){ 
                         if(!icon) icon = true;
                         else icon = false;
                     };
});
```

But doesn't work. some help please? thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're passing by value, so modifying `icon` will not change `icon1`. Instead, I would change your icon variables to an array and reference by index:

```
<div class="iconbar" ng-controller="icons">
    <span ng-click="iconclk(1)">icon</span>
<div ng-if="icon[1]">value</div>
</div>
```

Others will be `iconclk(2)`&`icon[2]`, `iconclk(3)`&`icon[3]`, and so on...

Controller:

```
app.controller('icons', function($scope) {
  $scope.icon = [false, false, false]; // or just [] if you want it to be simple
  $scope.iconclk = function(icon) {
    $scope.icon[icon] = !$scope.icon[icon];
  };
});
```